# Get Json list from Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json.net

I'm using $.ajax Get method to get list of JSon objects.
My jquery is

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'ItemHandler',             
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'                
                },
complete: function(items) {
    $.each(items,function(i,object){
       alert(object)
     }
   }
});
```

And the ItemHandler is like this

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   List<JObject> jsonList = new List<JObject>();
   List<Item> items = GetItems();
   foreach(Item item in items)
   {
     //string str = Append properties with values to the string
      jsonList.Add(JObject.Parse(str));
   }

   context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
   context.Response.Write(jsonList);
}
```

From ItemHandler it adds created Json object to the jsonList correctly and write to the context.response.
But within the jquery loop it doesn't give me the object. It shows undefined as in the alert.
I need to get each object from there.

Comment: Have you tried `success`? also try to log `items` before iterating.

Comment: Yes success doesn't give anything.

Comment: Hello snj debug and see whether your jsonList contains json string or not if it contains list object then serialize it into the json as per below and pass to front end.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. In my json list some objects has special characters like "\". In this case it's not showing withing the jquery. How to handle this special characters with json.net.

Answer (score 2):

Pass following in response

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonList);
```

this will convert your result into json.